# how to display registration data in table

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to registraton data display in the table but not displaying data

I have currently two records and I want to display them in the table

registration.component.html

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <h3>Registration</h3>
  <div>
    <div>
      <label>UserName:</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="txtusername" id="username" type="text" required />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Address:</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="txtempaddress" id="empaddress" type="text" required />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Password:</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="txtpassword" id="password" type="text" required />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Country:</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="txtcountry" id="country" type="text" required />
    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="registration()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>username</th>
      <th>empaddress</th>
      <th>password</th>
      <th>country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of elist;">
      <td>{{item.username}}</td>
      <td>{{item.empaddress}}</td>
      <td>{{item.password}}</td>
      <td>{{item.country}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

registration.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BackendserviceService } from '../backendservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration',
  templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration.component.css']
})
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

  txtusername: any;
  txtempaddress: any;
  txtpassword: any;
  txtcountry: any;

  elist: any;

  constructor(public myservice: BackendserviceService) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.list();
  }

  registration() {
    console.log("Inside registration method----------------- ")
    this.myservice.CreateUser(this.txtusername, this.txtempaddress, this.txtpassword, this.txtcountry).then((data: any) => {
      console.log("registration sucessfully");
      this.list();
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));;
  }

  list() {
    debugger
    console.log("list----------------- ")
    this.myservice.emplist().then((data: any) => {
      console.log("list data")
      this.elist = [];
      this.elist = data.data.elist;
      console.log("this.emplist ", this.elist)
    });
  }
}
```

backendservice.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BackendserviceService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

   public emplist() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      debugger
      var url = "https://localhost:44371/emps";

      this.httpClient.post<any>(url,null).subscribe(
        (res) => {
          console.log(res);
          resolve(res);
        },
        (err) => console.log(err)
      );
    });
  }
}
```

see console log:

[image]

see my console log I have currently two records and I want to display them in the table

how to display data in table format

see log I have 2 records and I want to display them in the table

help

Comment: I think I am here making mistake ```*ngFor="let item of elist;``` see my console log have 2 records I want to display them in the table which place I am making a mistake

Comment: What response shows there is no eList key in the response so instead of this `this.elist = data.data.elist;` try `this.elist = data.data;`.

Comment: @KamranKhatti  ```this.elist = data.data;``` undefined

Comment: `console.log(data)` see what it prints.

Comment: Also in your service method `emplist` you are using `post` instead of `get` I dont know how you are getting those two records

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220137/discussion-between-rahul-and-kamran-khatti).

Comment: The answer which you accepted was initially posted by me it was copied by that developer and used and you accepted that :(

Comment: @Kamran Khatti yes you are right I fix it and this line work for me ```console.log(data)``` because all data display in console browser

Comment: Then I am moving my comment to an answer and you can accept that answer okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the error says is, that you want to access elist of an undefined value. `data.data` is undefined here, hence `data` does not exist on `data`. You might want to have `this.elist = data`.

Answer (score 0):

What response in snapshot shows there is no `elist` key in the response.

Hence your `list()` method should be like this

```
elist = [];

 list() {
   this.myservice.emplist().then((data: any) => {
   this.elist = data;
  });
}
```